# How do I write Objects through a ObjectOutputStream, when the Objects are created in a different class?

Tags: java, encryption, inputstream, outputstream

I've tried to sum up my question, but really there's more behind it. For a task at uni we are supposed to create two constructors (English isn't my first language)

1) public SecureInputStream(InputStream base, OutputStream remote)

2) public SecureOutputStream(OutputStream base, InputStream remote)

1) is supposed to create BigIntegers g,n,k then generate a public key 
`K=g^k mod n`, then send `g`,`n` and `k` via remote to the other side, afterwards it is suppose to read the other sides `k` and create the secret `s= k^k mod n` and initiate the random generator with it. I am supposed to override 
`write(int b)`, so write will encrypt s, using the method xor out of the BigInteger class and then send it via remote to the other side.

2) is supposed to await g.n from 1), create it's own k and then send it back via remote. The constructor will also initiate the random generator using the secret s

Our instructor gave us two "easy" classes client and server, which use the Socket,Port Situation. My problem with that is, that the classes each have an own input/output stream that reads/writes something. How do i get in between there, and more importantly where the heck does the information that is send land once it is read? For two days all I'm doing is reading online and watching tutorials. I have definitely understood what streams are, although I can't really understand how they work.

How can I send several things through that stream? How does the other side know which of what I'm sending is which? How do I send stuff in general?

I hope someone can help me here. Well here's the code i have so far, the main method is from our instructor. Imagine I made all the imports.

```
//Error Method: Invalid method declaration, return type missing,
//I'm guessing the constructor needs to sit in a class called 
//SecureInputStream, but how can I use the stuff in the class Client
//when the constructor I need is in another?

public SecureInputStream(InputStream base, OutputStream remote) {
    super();
    //g,n,k,s are created 
    BigInteger g = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, new SecureRandom());
    BigInteger n = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, new SecureRandom());
    BigInteger k = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, new SecureRandom());
    BigInteger s = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, new SecureRandom());
    Random r = new Random();
    r.nextInt();
    BigInteger exponent1 = new BigInteger("r");
    BigInteger exponent2 = new BigInteger("k");
    k = g.modPow(exponent1, n);
    s = k.modPow(exponent2, n);

}

public static void main(String... args) {

    Socket server = null;

    try {
        // Connect to server on local machine ("localhost") and port 3145.
        server = new Socket("localhost", 3145);

        // Get input stream from server and read its message
        Scanner in = new Scanner(server.getInputStream());
        // If we need to send messages to the server:
        // OutputStream out = server.getOutputStream();

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (server != null) {
                server.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: every time a programmer writes an empty `catch` clause a panda bear dies.

Comment: Just a quick hint - check out the source code of Java BufferedinputStream/BufferdOutputStream. If doesn't solve your exercise, but it demonstrates the Decorator pattern. That's how you "get between" existing streams... you don't! You wrap them. E.g your server's basic OutputStream does an excellent job in transferring raw bytes. So let it be. Just wrap it with a secure output stream that would receive data to write(), translate it into encrypted raw bytes, then push those raw bytes into the basic stream.

Comment: (cont'd) there are some finer points I don't have time to consider throughly. E.g. the initial handshake (key exchange) which you might perform on the Constructors, or perhaps lazily on the first read/write.   And e.g. I'm not sure why your Secure Streams receive 2 constructor params (inputStream and OutputStream)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I write Objects through an `ObjectOutputStream,`

You call `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject().`

- 2nd question that you didn't ask: how do I read objects through an `ObjectInputStream`?

You call `ObjectInputStream.readObject().`

- 3rd question that you didn't ask: how can I discover the type of an incoming object?

You can discover the type of the received object via the `instanceof` operator. But with most protocols, including the protocol you described, you don't need to do that. The protocol normally defines what is sent when, so all you have to do is read accordingly.

> when the Objects are created in a different class?

It doesn't make any difference where the objects were created.

Comment: ... except if they are created in different Java runtimes. The classes in the runtimes need to be compatible. Personally I would rather think up a protocol and use `BigInteger.toByteArray()`. For an assignment the object streams should however suffice.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The question is 'How do I write Objects through a ObjectOutputStream, when the Objects are created in a different class?' An object to be written to an `ObjectOutputStream` must have been created in the same JVM.

Comment: Eh, of course. It's just that the object stream should be read by a compatible runtime. I'm not invalidating the answer, I just added a bit of a warning in case somebody uses it for a generic protocol - the objects are send over a socket, who knows where they end up.